# Procedure created with compilation errors , not getting help in it

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fetch( data OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS
    BEGIN
      OPEN data  FOR SELECT * FROM user_errors;
    END;
/





 Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

i tried but not getting why i am getting error like this , even in many example on internet i follow same  but not get help
Oracle 19c version

Comment: `FETCH` is a reserved word, I think. `select * from user_errors;` will show you the error.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH , after changing it Fetch to FetchData it now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FETCH` is a reserved word in PL/SQL. Use another name for your stored procedure.

You are shown errors with

```
select * from user_errors;
```

In your case you are getting:

| NAME | TYPE | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FETCH | PROCEDURE | 1 | 1 | 11 | PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting one of the following: current delete exists prior | ERROR | 103 |

When compiling the package with another name, you'll get another error :-) Because `CURSOR` is no data type. Use `SYS_REFCURSOR` instead.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=33d92c7ed3d254f672affd57bd66dbdd

Comment: SYS_REFCURSOR  it was before same and that time changing it to cursor i thought me change result but same ,
then 
re take SYS_REFCURSOR and  change fetch into FetchData , now it get compile Successfully 
Now can you please thought me how to call it